# IEnumerable<T> is throwing missing a using directive or an assembly reference (Using C#3.5)?

Tags: generics, c#-3.0, ienumerable

Getting the following error:
The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). What did I miss?

For the code below:

```
 public static IEnumerable<T> GetRequest(
                            string storedProcedureName,
                            Func<IEnumerable<T>> enumerateMethod)
        {
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                var com = new SqlCommand();
                com.Connection = conn;
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                com.CommandText = storedProcedureName;
                var adapt = new SqlDataAdapter();
                adapt.SelectCommand = com;
                var dataset = new DataSet();
                adapt.Fill(dataset);

                return enumerateMethod(dataset.Tables[0]);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare generic parameter `T` somewhere: either at method level:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetRequest<T>(...)
```

or at class level

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
     public static IEnumerable<T> GetRequest(...)
     {
         // (...)
     }
}
```